Blazor update a label after selecting option from dropdown list; remove option for other lists after selected
I have a of Hexes, buildings/improvments and NPC Hirelings. I would like to nest via a loop the Hexes, buildings/improvments and NPC Hirelings so that I can assign a hireling to a building that belongs to a Hex via a drop down. And once the Hireling is selected populate a label with some text and also remove/disable the hireling from all other drop down.
    <table class="w-50">
        @foreach (var hxs in HexName)
        {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><h3> @hxs.HexName Hex</h3></td>
            </tr>
                @foreach (var imps in Improvment) if (@hxs.HexName == imps.ImprovementHex)
                {
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">@imps.ImprovementName - @imps.ImprovementMaterial</td>
                </tr>
                    @for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td class="p-3">
                            <select class="form-select">
                                    <option />
                                    @foreach (var hire in Hirelings)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@hire.HirelingId">@hire.HirelingName</option>
                                    }
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        <td class="p-3"> <p>some text heere</p></td>
                        </tr>
                    }
            
                }

        }
    </table>

@code {
    private List<Improvements> Improvment = ImprovementsRepository.GetImprovements();

    private List<MapHex> HexName = MapHexRepository.GetMapHex();

    private List<Hireling> Hirelings = HirelingRepository.GetHirelings();

    private string? TotalValue { get; set; }

}

I have tried using ChatGPT and Gemini to help create the code but I cannot get it to work.

First, try to avoid for loop in razor code.
You can find the reason well explained here : https://shauncurtis.github.io/Building-Blazor-Applications/For-ForEach-in-Blazor.html
Secondly, when you select a option in your dropdown, you need to retrive the selected value and handle it.
If you don't need async call, you easilly can add a binded property :
<select class="form-select" @bind="@SelectedHire">
    @foreach (var hire in Hirelings)
    {
        <option value="@hire.HirelingId">@hire.HirelingName</option>
    }
</select>



@code {

    private Hireling selectedHire;
    private Hireling SelectedHire
    {
       get => selectedHire;
       set
       {
          // Do what you want to check if you can select the new value
          selectedHire = value;
          // Do what you want once the hire has been selected
       }
    }

}

If you need async calls, you can listen the @onchange event :
<select class="form-select"  @onchange=HandleHireChange>
    @foreach (var hire in Hirelings)
    {
        <option value="@hire.HirelingId">@hire.HirelingName</option>
    }
</select>



@code {

    private Hireling selectedHire;
    
    
    private async Task HandleHireChange(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedHireId = e.Value.ToString();
        
        selectedHire = Hirelings.SingleOrDefault(x => x.HirelingId == selectedHireId);
        
        // Do any async call if needed
        
    }
}

